# Weld injected HttpSession into the session scoped bean is null

Tags: java, gwt, jetty, cdi, weld

I'm running GWT app on Jetty 6.1 with Weld 2.0.
Got the next code:

```
    @SessionScoped
    public class SessionContext implements Serializable {

        @Inject
        private HttpSession httpSession;

        public SessionContext() {
            super();
            //at this point httpSession is null
        }
    }
```

What am I missing, why HttpSession is not injected? Reference says that `Injecting the HttpSession will force the session to be created.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of

```
public SessionContext() {
        super();
        //at this point httpSession is null
}
```

to

```
public SessionContext(HttpSession httpSession) {
        super();
        this.httpSession = httpSession;
        //check session here
}
```

Also use constructor injection

Otherwise provide a setter method for `httpSession`

Comment: Thanks, that helped out. But I must mention that anyway there MUST be a no-parameters default constructor.

Comment: Have a default ctor, and use a `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `@PostConstruct` to annotate some other method, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html) you have :

> Initializing a managed bean specifies the lifecycle callback method
>   that the CDI framework should call after dependency injection but
>   before the class is put into service.

This is exactly the place where your injections are done but no code has been invoked.

like this :

```
@PostConstruct
public void doMyStuff() {
  //feel free to access your injections here they are not null!
}
```